# CodeIgniter CSRF and localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I am currently working locally (myhostname.local) to begin a development project in CodeIgniter and am trying to do a simple login form submission and the CSRF protection is not working.  I get the error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>      The action you have requested is not allowed.

A couple of things to note:

1. I am using CI Reactor 2.0.2
2. I am running everything from a local host (myhostname.local)

My form:

```
<?=form_open('home/login');?>
... username/password fields in here ...
<?=form_close();>
```

My controller:

```
public function login()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        ... form did not pass validation ...
    }
    else
    {
        ... form passed ...
    }

}
```

When I submit the form to http://myhostname.local/home/login I get the above error.

Any help on why this is happening is much appreciated.

Thanks!
Sean

Comment: Does this happen every single time, or only sometimes, or only after a validation failure? Also, are you sure it's localhost only - does this work on a live server for you?

Comment: It happens every time. I have not tested it on a live server. I'll do that and let you know.

Comment: That might help, especially since the title is "CodeIgniter CSRF and localhost", it may be something to do with cookies not being set, are you able to set and read cookies? Make totally sure you see the CSRF token in the html source too, I know it sounds dumb but it's good to check the simplest things first.

Comment: Have you loaded the form validation library? just to makesure...

Comment: @Wesley Murch - I see cookies, and I can set cookies, but there is no cookie for the CSRF.  Also, the CSRF token is in source.  I've uploaded the site to a live server per your request: http://modernstitches.seangates.com/

Comment: @Karthik - the Form Validation library is autoloaded.  I'll double-check, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @Wesley Murch - Okay, I cleared out my settings for cookies in the config.php file and now I can finally see the CSRF cookie.  I guess it didn't like my settings. Thanks!! So ... now I have another problem and can't receive any POST variables and my validation isn't working. Hmmmm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that setting values in the config.php file for cookies has a big impact. 
Once I set these back to defaults everything started working correctly again:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']    = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case (Apache 2.2.24 on MacOSX). But i took it one step further and added this 
if (ENVIRONMENT==='development')  $config['cookie_domain']='';
right after cookie_ section in config.php
this way it will work if you deploy to production/stage env.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered a similar issue; I keep getting "The action you have requested is not allowed." error message when I am trying to submit my login form. I am working locally with a virtual linux box. It turned out that my problem had something to do with date time setup on the virtual machine. Once I update date to match my host machines date time, the problem disappears.

I am using CondeIgniter v. 2.1.0.

Here are parts of my config.php file:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'my_csrf_token';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'mycsrf';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

I hope this info helps someone experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Running CI 2.1.0 on a localhost setup with MAMP.

Installation of CI is brand new, with no extras. Simply following along the 'Tutorial' in the User Guide, and came across the same error after creating my first form, and enabling CSRF in the configs.

The 'form_open()' is used to open the form. The hidden field is being created. The error appears *every* time: "the action you have requested is not allowed".

After playing around with the cookie config options in config.php, as suggested here, I found that in my case the culprit seems to be the 'cookie_prefix' config. It must be left BLANK, otherwise it causes this error. Once it is left blank, everything works.

I hope this may prove useful to others.